# How to remove previous map route in windows phone 8 maps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps

I'm using map control in Windows Phone 8 application where i can display the desired locations and the directions for them, i can display the directions but if i give new search it is not removing the previous path how to remove the  previous path here is code i have used by following the below link :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244363(v=vs.105).aspx

Help me out please, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the corresponding `RemoveRoute` function, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.removeroute(v=vs.105).aspx